# Get current user name into the single line of text field for newform.aspx using Javascript in New Item form

Tags: sharepoint-designer, javascript, custom-list, content-editor-web-part

newitem.aspx opening into the popup, so where do I need to add Content editor webpart.
While opening newitem form, I need to autopopulate current user Name into sigle line text field?

Comment: How can we get sharepoint current user

Answer (score 0):

You can use REST API to get the current user login name and append that value to the SharePoint text field using jQuery.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type=text/javascript>
window.onload = function () {   
var userDisplayName = '';
$.ajax({  

        url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager/GetMyProperties",  
        headers: { Accept: "application/json;odata=verbose" },  
        aync:false,
        success: function (data) {  
            try {  
                //Get properties from user profile Json response  
                userDisplayName = data.d.DisplayName; 


            $('#ctl00_ctl63_g_31e84c00_425a_4193_9323_01cf5f3fd8e9_ff11_ctl00_ctl00_TextField').val(userDisplayName).prop('readonly', true).css('background-color', 'lightgrey');    // change the id of textfield (just inspect element your form and copy the id)
    }
            catch (err2) {                
            } 
        },  
        error: function (jQxhr, errorCode, errorThrown) {  
            alert(errorThrown);  
        }  
    }); 
}
</script>
```

Just add this code in your NewForm.aspx page.

Comment: thanks In newform.aspx where I need to put this code ?

Comment: @user47524 You can open the newform.aspx in SPD and insert this in <script></script>. Also, don't forget to load the jquery , sp.js files OR
you can edit the newform.aspx page and insert the script in Script Editor webpart

Comment: Thanks Sohail....I got it. I will add this code into the <script></script>. how would I need to load jquery , sp.js files. ? any code line I need to include into the <script></script>?

Comment: Just add this code in newform.aspx and if you get any error related to jQuery then add the reference of jQuery file before this code.

Comment: added same code into Script Editor webpart, but no luck.User name is not populationg

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
    at window.onload (NewForm.aspx?Source=

Comment: Please respond @sohail

Comment: $ is not defined means jQuery is not loaded. So include a reference of jQuery file above this code as 
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script> 
I have edited it in above code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/83991/discussion-between-sohail-shaikh-and-user47524).

Comment: I have added the reference still I am getting the same error

Answer (score 0):

Check this out once ...

`var selectedActivity;`

$(document).ready(function(){

```
$("input[Title='Name']").attr("disabled", "disabled");
populateCurrentUser();
```

});

function populateCurrentUser()
{
    var currentUserId;
    var currentUserName;
    var userLoginName;
    var peoplePickerFieldName = "People Picker";
    $.ajax({
            url: "https://xyz.sharepoint.com/ListName/_api/web/currentUser",
            method: "GET",
            headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" },
            async: false,
            success: function (data) {
                currentUserId = data.d.Id;
                currentUserName = data.d.Title;
                //userLoginName = data.d.LoginName;
            },
            error: function (error)
            {
                alert(error);
            }
        });
    $("input[Title='Name']").val(currentUserName);

}

function PreSaveAction() {

```
$("input[Title='Name']").attr("disabled",false);
return true;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You can use _spPageContextInfo in your JavaScript code
Add below line in your document.ready function

```
$("input[Title='Title Required Field']").val(_spPageContextInfo.userDisplayName);
```